# Adjust the line according to the screen width

Tags: org-mode

I copied a long sentence to org-mode

> As I mentioned in the last section, Richard Stallman, the founder of the Free Software Foundation, was more than a programmer. He was an educated social critic, and his vision of the future was to have an enormous impact on the world.
>   [image]

I tried to achieve line-break automatically with auto-fill-mode, but get a result as

[image]

How could I enable it to extend and shrink according the the screen width rather than the line limitation of 80 words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want "hard" returns at the end of lines, and you instead just want "soft" returns.  That is, you don't want to insert end-of-line characters, such as `newline`.  You just want lines to *appear* broken, and you want the apparent line breaks to be just before the window edge.  Is that right?

If so, what you want is to just turn on **`visual-line-mode`** in a given buffer -- or **`global-visual-line-mode`**, if you want this behavior in all buffers.  (And turn off `auto-fill-mode`.)

`C-h f visual-line-mode` tells you this:

> **`visual-line-mode`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `simple.el`.
>
> `(visual-line-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Toggle visual line based editing (Visual Line mode) in the current buffer.
>
> Interactively, with a prefix argument, enable
>   Visual Line mode if the prefix argument is positive,
>   and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, toggle
>   the mode if `ARG` is `toggle`, disable the mode if `ARG` is
>   a non-positive integer, and enable the mode otherwise
>   (including if `ARG` is omitted or `nil` or a positive integer).
>
> When Visual Line mode is enabled, `word-wrap` is turned on in
>   this buffer, and simple editing commands are redefined to act on
>   visual lines, not logical lines.  See Info node [Visual Line Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

create a function that sets the fill-mode width to (window-width) and add it to the post-command-hook

Comment: An example would make this answer much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>C-x f</kbd> to set a `fill-column` variable.
<kbd>M-q</kbd> to fill paragraph or selection to that width.

### As a minor mode:

```el
(defun dynamic-fill-column-set-var (frame)
  (when dynamic-fill-column-mode
    (setq fill-column (- (window-total-width) 3))))

(defun dynamic-fill-column-buffer-list-change ()
  (when dynamic-fill-column-mode
    (setq fill-column (- (window-total-width) 3))))

(define-minor-mode dynamic-fill-column-mode
  "Sets `fill-column' when buffer's window is resized"
  :lighter " DFC"
  (if dynamic-fill-column-mode
      (progn
        (add-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'dynamic-fill-column-set-var nil t)
        (add-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'dynamic-fill-column-buffer-list-change nil t))
    (remove-hook 'window-size-change-functions 'dynamic-fill-column-set-var t)
    (remove-hook 'buffer-list-update-hook 'dynamic-fill-column-buffer-list-change t)))
```

after resizing <kbd>M-q</kbd>(executes `fill-paragraph` function).